# Pandas : Reading first n rows from parquet file?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I have a parquet file and I want to read first `n` rows from the file into a pandas data frame.
What I tried:

```
df = pd.read_parquet(path= 'filepath', nrows = 10)
```

It did not work and gave me error:

```
TypeError: read_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nrows'
```

I did try the `skiprows` argument as well but that also gave me same error.

Alternatively, I can read the complete parquet file and filter the first n rows, but that will require more computations which I want to avoid.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Partial row-wise reads of Parquet files are now possible (using PyArrow as the backend), as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69888274/9962007

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The accepted answer is out of date. It is now possible to read only the first few lines of a parquet file into pandas, though it is a bit messy and backend dependent.

To read using PyArrow as the backend, follow below:

```
from pyarrow.parquet import ParquetFile
import pyarrow as pa 

pf = ParquetFile('file_name.pq') 
first_ten_rows = next(pf.iter_batches(batch_size = 10)) 
df = pa.Table.from_batches([first_ten_rows]).to_pandas()
```

Change the line `batch_size = 10` to match however many rows you want to read in.

Comment: And it is quite fast too (for 1m rows x 2k cols it takes 10 sec.)

Comment: Can we read random rows also?

Comment: And for S3....?

Comment: Can you also select certain rows to read @DavidKaftan? Example: from a very big parquet file, I'd like to read rows with index 13673, 14762 and 68712 only. How would you do this?

Comment: You can do this and many other sql-like operations using S3 Select from the AWS SDK for pandas (formerly AWS data-wrangler). See answer below

Answer (score 30):

After exploring around and getting in touch with the pandas dev team, the end point is pandas does not support argument `nrows` or `skiprows` while reading the parquet file.

The reason being that pandas use `pyarrow` or `fastparquet` parquet engines to process parquet file and `pyarrow` has no support for reading file partially or reading file by skipping rows (not sure about `fastparquet`). Below is the link of issue on pandas github for discussion.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24511

Answer (score 7):

### Querying Parquet with DuckDB

To provide another perspective, if you're comfortable with SQL, you might consider using [DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/execute_sql) for this. For example:

```
import duckdb
nrows = 10
file_path = 'path/to/data/parquet_file.parquet'
df = duckdb.query(f'SELECT * FROM "{file_path}" LIMIT {nrows};').df()
```

If you're working with partitioned parquet, the above result wont include any of the partition columns since that information isn't stored in the lower level files. Instead, you should identify the top folder as a partitioned parquet datasets and register it with a DuckDB connector:

```
import duckdb
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
nrows = 10
dataset = ds.dataset('path/to/data', 
                     format='parquet',
                     partitioning='hive')
con = duckdb.connect()
con.register('data_table_name', dataset)
df = con.execute(f"SELECT * FROM data_table_name LIMIT {nrows};").df()
```

You can register multiple datasets with the connector to enable more complex queries. I find DuckDB makes working with parquet files much more convenient, especially when trying to JOIN between multiple Parquet datasets. Install it with `conda install python-duckdb` or `pip install duckdb`

Answer (score 5):

Using [pyarrow](https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/) dataset scanner:

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

n = 10
src_path = "/parquet/path"
df = ds.dataset(src_path).scanner().head(n).to_pandas()
```

Answer (score 5):

The most straighforward option for me seems to use `dask` library as

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_parquet(path= 'filepath').head(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can use [S3 Select](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/029%20-%20S3%20Select.html) functionality from [AWS SDK for pandas](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) as [proposed by Abdel Jaidi in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72377467/how-do-i-use-awswrangler-to-read-only-the-first-few-n-rows-of-a-parquet-file-sto).

> pip install awswrangler

```
import awswrangler as wr

df = wr.s3.select_query(
        sql="SELECT * FROM s3object s limit 5",
        path="s3://filepath",
        input_serialization="Parquet",
        input_serialization_params={},
        use_threads=True,
)
```

Comment: the data may not be on s3

Comment: While this looks like a great approach, it unfortunately will not work for Parquet files with large block sizes.

Answer (score -2):

Parquet file is column oriented storage, designed for that... So it's normal to load all the file to access just one line.

Comment: Yes, parquet is column based. However, columns are divided into *row groups*. This means it is possible to only read a part of a parquet file (i. e. one row group). See https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/ and https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#finer-grained-reading-and-writing E. g. Apache Spark is able to read and process different row groups of the same parquet file on different machines in parallel.

Comment: However, row groups are pretty large. In Spark/Hadoop, the default group size is 128/256 MB

Comment: Saying that it is normal isn't very helpful when you get a 10GB worth of file with a billion rows where just 1 million would be more than enough for your needs.